# How to make too bold text in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

While using **Jetpack Compose** `Text()` I am not able to change the `fontWeight` more than `FontWeight.W600` and `FontWeight.W500`. Others than these two none gets applied like `FontWeight.W700`, `FontWeight.Bold` , `FontWeight(550)` etc. I was trying to create text  with too dark but not able to achieve at all. Note: I am using **Roboto** font from **google downloadable font** and `material theme 3`.

`One example of text code:-`

```
Text(
   modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 4.dp),
   text = "This should be too bold",
   style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleSmall,
   fontWeight = FontWeight.Black,
)
```

Comment: Have you used buildAnnotatedString?

Comment: Why don't you use `fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold` with a big fontSize?

Answer (score 10):

From [official Android Compose documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text/style-text#bold):

```
@Composable
fun BoldText() {
    Text("Hello World", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
}
```

If you need additional styles (from [Material Design 3 documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material3)):

```
Text(
   text = "Hello World",
   style = MaterialTheme.typography.displayLarge,
   color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
)
```

You can also try downloading the font from [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) by manually selecting the style `Black 900`:

[image]